# bash script stdout process in file doesn't work

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a wrapper for openvpn, so that the my program does not ask a second time for the root password when i need to close openvpn

```
#!/bin/bash
PATHTOME=$(pwd)
echo $PATHTOME

openvpn --config $PATHTOME/testVPN.ovpn &> $PATHTOME/ovpn_stdout.txt

until false
do
    enabvalue=`cat ovpn_enable.txt`
    echo $enabvalue

    if [ "$enabvalue" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "enabled"
    else
        echo "bye"
        kill -9 $(ps aux | grep testVPN.ovpn | grep ^root | awk '{print $2}')
        exit 1
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

But it still does not write openvpn result to the file.
I need this because I can't read from the root of a process while it's running.

if i run `sudo sh startovpn.sh &> ovpn_stdout.txt`
then loop doesn't work :(
need help

p.s. i can't get PID in my main process when run this with sudo

Comment: What's in `ovpn_enable.txt`? Also, your use of `cat` is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of* `cat`). Instead `enabvalue=$(< ovpn_enable.txt)`. As shown the content would need to be a single `1` for your script to make sense. Have you pasted your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix the warnings yet?

Comment: What's `PATHTOME` supposed to be? The name suggests it's supposed to be the path to the script, but that's not what `pwd` gives you.